# c expression must have a constant value in 2d array

Tags: c, visual-studio

c expression must have a constant value in 2d array

> there error in int x[a][b]; in visual studio

```
int i, j,a,b;
scanf_s("%d", &a);
scanf_s("%d",&b);

int x[a][b];

for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        scanf_s("%d", &x[i][j]);
```

// why in visual studio error in    int x[a][b];

Comment: MSVC does not support variable length arrays. At one time they were required by the C standard, but not now (although MS has never supported them).

Comment: You could use dynamic allocation. Either by a 1-D array of pointers of length `a` each pointing to a 1-D array of length `b`,  or by a single 1-D array of length `a * b` where you work out the indexing for yourself. Another solution would be a fixed array with the input dimensions restricted to its defined size.

Comment: OT: Letting user input set the size of a VLA array **without** checking that the sizes are within a reasonable range is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Older Visual Studio versions simply didn't support standard C language.

In case of VS2019 or newer they implemented `__STDC_NO_VLA__` set to 1 as required by the standard when the compiler doesn't support variable-length arrays (VLA). Which doesn't help in your case, since the feature is still not there.

So either you need to stop using VLA or switch to a better compiler.

(Declaring actual VLA objects is a mildly useful feature that one can do without, but declaring pointers to VLA is essential in modern C programming.)